# BitBucket credentials popup broken in Visual Studio's Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket, msysgit

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 on a Win7 64 machine.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2014/07/visual-studio-2013-team-explorer-bit-bucket-git.html) to play around with BitBucket. Everything works fine up to the point where Visual Studio throws the authentication message box. This is what it should look like:

[image: expected popup]

The problem is that the dialog I get shown doesn't contain the middle part. There's the "Remember.." check box, and the buttons, but nothing to actually enter anything. OK ist deactivated and when I click Cancel I get an unathorized error shown in Team Explorer.